# check if a number is a multiple of another inside for

Tags: php

Hi to all I want to make a loop that returns only multiples of given number, this number can be only an integer value:
I tried

```
$number = 12;
$multiplier = 3;
for ( $i = 0; $i <= $number; $i++ ) {
   if ( is_int( $i / $multiplier ) ) {
   echo $i.' is a multiplier of '.$multiplier."\n";
   }

}
```

this is working but, cause I'm a little noob, something is telling me that there is a better way

Comment: You can use the modulus operator `%`, and check if the result is 0 or not.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php - check out modulo